# Correct way to return from mongo to datatable

Tags: mongodb, datatable, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and returning documents from a collection to be displayed using datatables. I'm having some issues though. The client-side code is

```
    var table = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable( {
          "bProcessing" : true,
          "bServerSide" : true,
          "ajax" : {
            "url" : "/mongo/get/datatable",
            "dataSrc": ""
          },
          "columnDefs": [
            {
              "data": null,
              "defaultContent": "<button id='removeProduct'>Remove</button>",
              "targets": -1
            }
          ],
          "aoColumns" : [
            { "mData" : "name" },
            { "mData" : "price" },
            { "mData" : "category" },
            { "mData" : "description" },
            { "mData" : "image" },
            { "mData" : "promoted" },
            { "mData" : null}
          ]
        });
```

Then this handled on the server-side using the following

```
 db.once('open', function callback ()
    {
       debug('Connection has successfully opened');

       productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
          name: String,
          price: String,
          category: String,
          description: String,
          image: String,
          promoted: Boolean
       });

       Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema, 'products');
    });

    exports.getDataForDataTable = function (request, response) {
       Product.dataTable(request.query, function (err, data) {
      debug(data);
      response.send(data);
   });
};
```

If I use the above code the datatable fails to display the documents, claiming *no matching records found* **BUT** it does correctly display the number of docs *Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries*. If I change the server side code to response with `data.data` instead of `data`, the documents are correctly populated in the table **BUT** the number of records is no longer found, instead saying *Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)*

```
exports.getDataForDataTable = function (request, response) {
           Product.dataTable(request.query, function (err, data) {
          debug(data);
          response.send(data.data);
       });
```

The actual `data` being returned when querying mongo is

```
{ draw: '1', recordsTotal: 2, recordsFiltered: 2, data: [ { _id: 5515274643e0bf403be58fd1, name: 'camera', price: '2500', category: 'electronics', description: 'lovely', image: 'some image', promoted: true }, { _id: 551541c2e710d65547c6db15, name: 'computer', price: '10000', category: 'electronics', description: 'nice', image: 'iamge', promoted: true } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter in `mongoose.model` sets the collection name which is pluralized and lowercased automatically so it has no effect in this case.

Assuming your `Product` variable has been declared early on and global, try this:

`products = mongoose.model('products', productSchema);
 Product = require('mongoose').model('products');`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Try instead of what? What effect do you think this will have?

Comment: It is stolen from the official example at https://github.com/lepazmino/mongoose-datatable-demo/blob/master/mongo.js  I feel that when you are calling Product.dataTable, it is not being able to access the product schema and thus having issue formatting the retrieved data to the specified bson/json.

Comment: Generally speaking, keeping your models inside a model folder, initiating the plugin there and exporting the model is a better software architecture pattern rather than defining the schema inside db.once.

Comment: That still doesn't fix it for me unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the dataSrc field in the DataTable configuration:

```
"ajax" : {
    "url" : "/mongo/get/datatable",
},
```

Comment: If you know the dataSrc is a problem, then say so. If you're not sure, try it yourself before suggesting. If you're just guessing, post as a comment to the question, not as an answer.